# Add images on chart control

Tags: c#, graphics, charts, microsoft-chart-controls

I'm not sure if I titled the question correctly so it would be better if I explained what I'm trying to do. I want to add some images on chart control and 
around their to draw graphics.

I want to display the layout of the sensors on the coordinate plane defined by coordinates, while noting the location of geographic objects (forest, river, etc.). These objects will be images which I want to add to the chart/

How can I do it? It is possible?

Comment: We need more info to answer your question correctly. For example what you're using to draw charts, what code have you tried and so on. :)
See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I added some information in my question

Comment: A chart is not a container control like Panel or Form.  Nevertheless, you can add pictureboxes with its Controls.Add() method and they'll show up on top of the chart.  There is a chicken-and-egg problem however, you can't know what their Location property needs to be until after the chart paints itself.  The smart thing to do here is to write an event handler for its PostPaint event and just draw whatever you need through its e.ChartGraphics property.  Including the images, use DrawImage().

Comment: Have you resolved your problems?

Answer (score 3):

If you show us an example we may be able to help to find the best way.

There are several options.:

- You can place image controls like `PictureBox` or `Panel` on the `Chart` by adding them to the chart's `Controls` collection
- You can draw them in the `Pre-` or `PostPaint` event
- You can assemble a `BackImage` that contains all the Images you want to place around the chart.
- You can add `ImageAnnotations` to the chart. (Recommended)

The latter obviously is the one that is best integrated.

Here is an example:

We start by adding the images we want to use to the Chart's `Images` collection:

```
List<string> imgFiles = new List<string>()
{ yourImageFileName1, ...};

for (int i = 0; i  < imgFiles.Count; i++)
{
    Image img = Bitmap.FromFile(imgFiles[i]);
    chart1.Images.Add(new NamedImage("Image" + i, img));
}
```

Note the [`NamedImage`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.namedimage(v=vs.110).aspx) class used here. It allows you to refer to the images by a string; pick better names! Maybe `Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(imgFiles[i])` - Also note that you must **not** `Dispose` of the `Images` or else they will disappear!

Next make make a little room at the right side of the chart by reducing the `ChartArea`'s size:

```
ChartArea ca = chart1.ChartAreas[0];
ca.Position = new ElementPosition(5,5,70,90);
```

Note the values are **percentages** of the Chart's `ClientSize`, so they will grow and shrink when resizing the `Chart`!

Finally we can add them all. **You** will want to add them at specific positions. I add them at **some** space to the right and also make them moveable:

```
foreach (NamedImage img in chart1.Images)
{
    ImageAnnotation ia = new ImageAnnotation();
    ia.Image = img.Name;
    ia.AllowMoving = true;
    ia.X = 77;
    ia.Y = 15 * chart1.Images.IndexOf(img) + 5;
    chart1.Annotations.Add(ia);
}
```

Now you should see the `Annotions`. And if you add this event:

```
private void chart1_AnnotationPositionChanging(object sender, 
                                               AnnotationPositionChangingEventArgs e)
{
    testLabel.Text = e.Annotation.X + " "  + e.Annotation.Y;
}
```

..you will see just what the numbers for the best position are. Eventually you will not keep them moveable, of course..

Note the the `Annotations'` position is also in `percentages`, so they will move along nicely, when the chart get resized! You may also scale the Images by setting the `Width` and `Height`; this is a little tricky, as it will also be in **percent** (and **not** as the docs falsely state in **pixels**). You would probably want to loop over the ImageAnnotations and rescale them in the `Resize` event..: `ia.Height = ia.Width * chart1.Width /  chart1.Height;`

Also note that there are other ways to position annotations, like **anchored** to datapoints, but this seem the best for a static adornment.

[image]